# Web API: how to pass data between controller and business logic

Tags: architecture, controller, asp.net-core-webapi, dto, business-logic

I'm currently working on a solution with this architecture:

- `ApplicationCore` project (contains domain entities and business logic)
- `Infrastructure` project (contains specific infrastructure code like Entity Framework)
- `WebAPI` project (REST API for Angular front and other client services)

Let's imagine a web form to create for example a car, specifying main information and parts, that posts to a controller action like:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CarModel carModel)
```

where CarModel is:

```
public class CarModel 
{
  public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<CarPartModel> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class CarPartModel
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<CarPartAttributeModel> Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class CarPartAttributeModel
{
  public string Code { get; set; }
  public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

My Business Layer would contain an `ICarService` with a `CreateCar` method that would check all inserted data to validate it and apply some rules. Now, I don't know what's the proper way to pass that complex model from the controller to my business logic.

Two options came to my mind:

1. To put `CarModel` in my BLL and simply pass it to the `CreateCar` method
2. To create a similar DTO in the BLL and copy `CarModel` to that DTO to keep models inside the `WebAPI` layer

What is considered acceptable or best practise? Is there a third option?

Answer (score 2):

Answers to these types of questions are going to get opinionated, but I will offer up my general solution and you can take it for what it's worth.  I think it's a common method.

My WebAPI only interacts with DTOs, so the Create method would accept a CreateCarDto.  I assume in your code that CarModel is a DTO-like object and not your domain object. (side note, REST generally uses POST for create, not PUT which is for updating).  My controller then calls the Create method on my service passing in that DTO as a parameter.  The service Create method then does it's thing -- validation (I use FluentValidation) and then I map my DTO to a domain object before doing the DB work via EF.

For the setup you describe, I don't think you need three layers of objects (Model/DTO/Domain?).  Generally the public facing stuff will interact with a Model/DTO and the core services translate domain object to/from those DTOs.